# Calling numpy on parallel processors in IJulia notebook

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, julia, ijulia-notebook

I want to run a simple code in the IJulia notebook which uses the python library numpy. I call numpy with PyCall:

> using PyCall
>
> @pyimport numpy as np

This works fine. I then want to split this up to several processors. I add the processors:

> addprocs(4)

Then, I run N/proc iterations for a function f, where proc is my number of processors. I split the load evenly between the four processors on my computer:

> ```
> n=round(Int,N/proc);
>
> proc_sum = @parallel (+) for i=1:proc
>
>         f(n)
>
> end
>
> return proc_sum / proc
> ```

Without numpy, this works fine. However, when I try to split the code with numpy to different processors, I get the error

> ERROR (unhandled task failure): On worker 3:
>
> UndefVarError: np not defined

Is there any way to have numpy work on the other processors? Note that I have Julia 0.5.2, and I have Canopy. I know there have been issues reported before with PyCall and Canopy, but I would greatly prefer keeping Canopy on my machine.

Comment: Do `add_procs` before all other things, and do `@everywhere(@pyimport numpy as np)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further expand on what has been said already, everything you need should be loaded in all the processes. E. g. :

`addprocs(4)
@everywhere using PyCall
@everywhere @pyimport numpy as np`

What you wrote errored because all processes tried to use `@pyimport` but only the main process had `PyCall` loaded. If you require many packages to do your computations, maybe the easier is to do all the loading in one script, i.e. `load_modules.jl` and then simply run

`addprocs(4)
@everywhere include("load_modules.jl")`

EDIT: It seems that `using` is not very robust with `@everywhere` (fixed on Julia 0.6, see [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/21718)). What seems to work better is:

`addprocs(4)
import PyCall
@everywhere using PyCall
@everywhere @pyimport numpy as np`

Comment: I did use @everywhere when "using PyCall", but then I get the error "WARNING: replacing module PyCall"
 repeated four times.

Comment: Are you on Julia 0.6 ? It's probably this issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19187 . It's marked as solved, so it'll stop happening in the next release.

Comment: No, I am on Julia 0.5.2

Comment: I see. It's solved here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/21718. You can simply type in their solution and it should work, I'll update the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding on Lyndon's comment to provide a more comprehensive answer.

As per [the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing.html#Code-Availability-and-Loading-Packages-1), processes are independent, and thus rely on their own, independent workspace. Therefore, any functions, modules or variables that will be needed by a process need to be made available to that process first.

If you want to make something available to all existing processes, you can use the `@everywhere` macro; clearly, to make something available to "all existing processes", these processes need to have been created first.

So:

```
addprocs(4); # create 4 extra processes (i.e. workers); this is in addition
             # to the main process that handles the REPL

@everywhere import Pycall
@everywhere PyCall.@pyimport numpy as np # load module on _all_ 5 active processes
```

Comment: I still have an error: 
@everywhere(@pyimport numpy as np) tells me that "@pyimport not defined"

Comment: well, it sounds like @pyimport is not defined then, doesn't it! :)  Import it in the process before using it.